# How to show plot made in R in pycharm?

Tags: r, pycharm

I'm learning R, for one of my projects. I use it in combination with the JetBrains Pycharm IDE.

It seems that it has out of the box support for R. However when I plot something nothing shows up in the "SciView" or "R Graphics" window.

The R code does generate a pdf file with the correct plot.

I use this code:

```
# Title     : TODO
# Objective : TODO
# Created by: boatfolder
# Created on: 2019-03-04

print("Hello world")

# Define the cars vector with 5 values
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)

# Graph cars using blue points overlayed by a line
plot(cars, type="o", col="blue")

# Create a title with a red, bold/italic font
title(main="Autos", col.main="red", font.main=4)
```

And this is how the result looks like:

[image: result]

Why is it not showing up in the "SciView" or "R Graphics" window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's disable now:
https://github.com/holgerbrandl/r4intellij/issues/134

I use `jpeg(...)` to set ouput file name like:

```
jpeg("plot.jpg")
plot(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))
```

Hope it will be useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

Or add the absolute path to `jpeg()` function:

```r
# running on WSL 

cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)

jpeg(filename = "//wsl$//Ubuntu//path_to//<your_file>.jpg")
plot(cars)
```

[image]

---

If using [`ggsave`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/ggsave):

```r
# running on WSL

library(ggplot2)

set.seed(5)
x <- c(rnorm(200, mean = -2, 1.5),
       rnorm(200, mean = 3, sd = 1),
       rnorm(200, mean = 2, 1.5))
group <- c(rep("A", 200), rep("B", 200), rep("C", 200))
df <- data.frame(x, group)

ggsave(filename = "//wsl$//Ubuntu//path_to//<your_file>.jpg",
       plot = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, colour = group)) + geom_density())
```

[image]